# Springboot Sqlite database file locked error with no multithreading

Tags: sqlite

All answers I have come across on the sqlite database file getting locked problem involve simultaneous readers and writers. But I'm facing the issue even when running in single threaded mode, in an Integration test that I'm running with

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

Update: Without even understanding why it should help, I added synchronized statements in my code reading and writing to the database and after that the error did not happen.

Since springboot doesn't natively support sqlite, I have used a custom dialect file in

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=com.springboot.sqlite.SQLDialect
```

FWIW, I also have

```
spring.datasource.maxActive = 1
```

and also I have set write-ahead logging:

```
jdbcTemplate.execute("pragma journal_mode=WAL");
```

My test just runs several read and write operations in sequence but it fails with

```
The database file is locked (database is locked); nested exception is org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)

at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1542)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:393)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:558)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following configuration to application.properties

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=1
```

Comment: I had the same problem from the main post and tested this solution. It won't work with multiple threads writing to the SQLite db, the threads will lock when trying to access the DB simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue here, SQLite DB locking everytime when trying multiple read/writes from multiple threads.

What I did to fix the problem was to put the commands to read/write the repository (SQLite DB) inside a @Service class. Then annotate the corresponding functions with a @Async flag so it won't lock the main thread, and put access to the repository inside a "synchronized(repository)...".

Example:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Async
    public void accessDb() {

        synchronized (myRepository) {

                MyEntity myEntity = myRepository.findById(1);
                myEntity.setModifiedAt(new Date());
                myRepository.save(myEntity);

        }

    }

}
```